# Python - Filtering data from a string - before, in between and after commas

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I'm pretty new to programming and I`m starting learning Python.

For a little web scraping project, I'm using a code that collects via Xpath the following data as string.

The objective is get this data and convert square feet to square meters.

[image]

For this example the code returns this string: "47′-4″ wide,82′ deep,26′ high"

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import re

resp = requests.get(
                    url="https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/bedrooms/5-bedrooms/avenue/",
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

dimensions = tree.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'House Size')]/following-sibling::p/text()")

dimensions = ','.join(dimensions)

dimensions = dimensions.replace('\n', '')

print(dimensions)
```

Looking to this string: "47′-4″ wide,82′ deep,26′ high" I think the best way to do the conversion is filter the data in three parts: data before the first comma (47-4), then the data in between the first and the second comma (82) and finally the data that is after the second comma (26).

I think if I could get these 3 parts and storing it in three variables, I could test the variables to check when the format is different, for example, if a variable contains hifen (47-4), the script will get the first number as feet and the second as inches, so I can convert both of them to meters, sum and finally get this numbers converted in square meters.

If I test the variable and there's not contains a hifen I just convert feet to meters and that's it =)

Guys, do you think my idea is all right?

If yes, how to divide/get these three parts of this string?

I guess that using the commas as "pattern" will be the best way to separate, test and process using an IF...

Could you help me, guys?

Comment: For the task of splitting the string, use the aptly named split method:
`"This,will,work".split(',')` gives you a list with three entries, `["This", "will", "work"]`.

Then for each part you'd do your particular processing.

Looks like you already got `re` imported, so look into the regular expression matching there.

Comment: All right @Lagerbaer I'll read more about regular expressions... Maybe it will be the right way to do what I want... The main problem is that these data doesn't follows a pattern... Sometimes we get something like "47-4, 82, 26" in other cases I get a "30, 82-10, 26-3" you know? I need to find a way to test these parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have comma's and values in one strings is due to you calling .join() on the return of the web scrape.

The return is actually a list, and you can use the following to extract the values (regardless of formatting) as long as they are in the same order every time; wide, deep, high. `(See below for method of detecting regardless of order)`

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import re

resp = requests.get(
                    url="https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/bedrooms/5-bedrooms/avenue/",
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

dimensions = tree.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'House Size')]/following-sibling::p/text()")

wide = dimensions[0].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]
deep = dimensions[1].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]
high = dimensions[2].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]


print(wide)
print(deep)
print(high)
```

This returns;

```
47′-4″
82′
26′
>>>
```

You will then be able to perform your formatting check per measurement.

EDIT:

If the location of the measurements is variable, or changes. The below code will detect the measurement regardless of order;

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import re

resp = requests.get(
                    url="https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/bedrooms/5-bedrooms/avenue/",
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

dimensions = tree.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'House Size')]/following-sibling::p/text()")


wide = [v for v in dimensions if 'wide' in v]
deep = [v for v in dimensions if 'deep' in v]
high = [v for v in dimensions if 'high' in v]

wide = wide[0].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]
deep = deep[0].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]
high = high[0].replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0]


print(wide)
print(deep)
print(high)
```

EDIT:

You can further condense the above code into nice little one liners for each dimension.

```
wide = [v.replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0] for v in dimensions if 'wide' in v][0]
deep = [v.replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0] for v in dimensions if 'deep' in v][0]
high = [v.replace('\n', '').split(' ')[0] for v in dimensions if 'high' in v][0]

print(wide)
print(deep)
print(high)
```

Comment: man!  You just saved me! Thank you so much, bro! I'm really learning a lot over here! Thanks!

Comment: You're amazing!

Comment: Good to see you're learning! @FranciscoSanchez I have added another example at the bottom which condenses the above into one line per dimension. Beauty of list comprehension.

Comment: Pretty clean! Someday I'll be able to code like that! That's great! lol nowadays my code is awfully ugly. But with practice it will get better.

Answer (score 2):

A simple strategy of parsing the content is via regexes. In your code, add the following line at the bottom of your code, after `dimensions = dimensions.replace('\n', '')`:

```py
dimensions = re.match("(?P<wide>.+) wide,(?P<deep>.+) deep,(?P<high>.+) high", dimensions).groupdict()
```

You can then obtain the dimensions via normal dict-like methods:

```py
dimensions["wide"]
dimensions["deep"]
dimensions["high"]
```

Comment: Hey @RichieBendall thanks for your explanation! I'm trying to learn more about regexes! It's so much powerfull!